# Line up two table columns to each other

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is it possible to line up these two tablecolums so cell 1a is in line with cell 2a? As it is right now the outer left column seem to be vertically centered to the outer right column

Further down is the source (html) and then a screenshot

```html
<table>
  <tr> 
    <td>
      <table class="payment"> 
        <tr>
          <td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>info (1a)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> descr ...</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="payment"> 
        <tr>
          <td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>info (1b)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> descr ...</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="payment"> 
        <tr>
          <td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>info (1c)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> descr ...</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>

    <!-- OUTER COLUMN 2 -->
    <td>
      <table class="payment"> 
        <tr>
          <td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>info (2a)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> decr ...</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="payment">
        <tr>
          <td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>info (2b)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> descr ...</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="payment">
        <tr>
          <td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>info (2c)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> descr ...</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table class="payment">
        <tr>
          <td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
          <td>info (2d)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td> descr ...</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

image
[image]

Comment: Do you need to use a separate table for each item?

Comment: @Jimmy - yes i think i need it

Comment: [And do you really need to use tables for layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Straight html add `valign=top` to you first `tr`:

```
<table>
    <tr valign=top> 
        <td>

        <table class="payment"> 
            <tr>
                <td> <input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>info (1a)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

That is, unless something in the `class="payment"` style is effecting the positioning